# Python - reading 2D codes, improper output in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using libdmtx to read 2D codes from png files with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry("200x200")
content = StringVar()
label = Message( top, textvariable=content, width='180' )
content.set ("Choose file to read 2D code")
label.pack()

def selector():
   filename = askopenfilename() 
   cmd = "dmtxread -n %s" % (filename)
   res = Text(top)
   res.insert (INSERT, os.system(cmd))
   res.pack()

B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Choode file", command = selector)
B.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Everything work fine, but in GUI I can't get a full output. There's just 0, but in console I get what is in 2D code. 
What should I do to get full output in GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) doesn't return the `stdout` of the command you executed, it just returns its exit status, which is in this case `0`.

You should use the `subprocess` module, like this:

```
import subprocess

def selector():
    filename = askopenfilename() 
    p = subprocess.Popen(["dmtxread", "-n", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    res.insert(INSERT, stdout)
    res.pack()
```

Comment: The OP may also want to consider [subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) which makes this simpler

Comment: I might want to consider it too :) Thanks for the tip!